# MVC AjaxOption not showing spinner on right location?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to show a spinner on overlay on the partial view while loading another partial view. But, it is showing where the div was declared.

### Index.cshtml

```
<div id="DivEmailContainer" style="display:block" class="row">
    @Html.Partial("_DisplayContactEmail",Model)
</div>
<div id="spinnerdiv" style="display:none;">         
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x"></i>
</div>
```

### _DisplayContactEmail.cshtml

```
<td class="">
     @Ajax.ActionLink(
           "Edit",
           "GetEditEmail",
           new { CommunicationLocation = commemail.Location },
           new AjaxOptions()
           {
                HttpMethod = "Get",
                UpdateTargetId = "DivEmailContainer",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                LoadingElementId = "spinnerdiv"
           },
           new { @class = "linkbutton" })

</td>
```

It suppose to show on top of partialview.

[image]

What could be wrong?

Comment: Your "spinnerdiv" is below the partial view. How do you expect it to be on top of it, when it's not? Just move the div to the top of the partial view.

Answer (score 0):

The `LoadingElementId` option is set to the id of the element (normally a div or a span) that you want to be displayed during the time the Ajax call is sent to the server and until a response is received. In your case, you're using the id of a div element which is placed below the partial view on your page. If you want the spinner to be displayed on top of the partial view, simply move the div to the top:

```
<div id="spinnerdiv" style="display:none;">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x"></i>
</div>
<div id="DivEmailContainer" style="display:block" class="row">
    @Html.Partial("_DisplayContactEmail",Model)
</div>
```

Comment: you misunderstood. I want overlay the spinner on top of my partialview.

Comment: I didn't misunderstand. The spinner is inside the div. So, it will appear where the div is. It's as simple as that. However, the code in my answer is not the solution for what you want to achieve, if what you want to do is the spinner to be displayed over your partial view. You should be able to do that with some CSS. I'm not an expert on that.